# Use subprocess python library to unzip a file using 7zip

Tags: python, perl, 7zip

I would like to unzip a file with Python using 7zip executable. In Perl this is pretty straightforward:

```
$zip_exe_path = "C:\\Dropbox\\7-zip\\7z.exe";
$logfile_path = "C:\\Temp\\zipped_file.7z";
system ("$zip_exe_path x $log_file_path -y");
```

I tried this:

```
import subprocess
zip_exe_path = "C:\\Dropbox\\7-zip\\7z.exe"
logfile_path = "C:\\Temp\\zipped_file.7z"
subprocess.call(['zip_exe_path','x','logfile_path','-y'])
```

When I do so I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that you are passing the *strings* `'zip_exe_path'` and `'logfile_path'` instead of the values of those variables.

```py
import subprocess
zip_exe_path = "C:\\Dropbox\\7-zip\\7z.exe"
logfile_path = "C:\\Temp\\zipped_file.7z"
subprocess.call([zip_exe_path, 'x', logfile_path, '-y'])
```

You can of course pass the command as a single string with `shell=True` but the shell does not add any value and [incurs some overhead (and risk!)](/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Answer (score 3):

Why not use python **zip**:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile(logfile_path, 'r') as z:
    z.extractall()
```

Or using subprocess:

```
subprocess.call(['zip_exe_path','x','logfile_path','-y'], shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That doesn't work because zipfile doesn't work on other .zip formats like .7z or .rar.

Comment: Use py7zlib in such case

Comment: I did but it has problems handling corrupt files. Which is why I would like to use system commands.

Comment: in that case add shell=True to your subprocess call

Comment: if downvote please leave a comment, so i would know how to correct the answer, otherwise your downvote is useless

Comment: we can specify the specific path in `z.extractall(path)` to extract the files at a particular location.

Answer (score 3):

**This work like a charm for me :)**

first, install py7zr library:

```
pip install py7zr
```

for extracting all files in .7z:

```
from py7zr import py7zr

with py7zr.SevenZipFile('7z file_location', mode='r') as z:
    z.extractall()
```

for extracting a single file:

```
from py7zr import py7zr

with py7zr.SevenZipFile('7z file_location', mode='r') as z:
    z.extract(targets=['rootdir/filename'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(zip_exe+' x '+file+' -o'+output_loc,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Switching from `call` to `Popen` is not an  improvement here. Requiring a shell is also not an improvement.